# Python - class decorator - runtime inheritance

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

I am trying to create a decorator that will inject some functionality to wrapped class `__init__` method. This is what works.

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, cls):
        print(cls)

        class Wrapped(cls):
            def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
                cls.__init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs)
                print('in wrapped init', self.variable)

        return Wrapped


@Decorator('random_string')
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
        self.variable = 10
        print('TestClass init')


test = TestClass(first_arg='one', second_arg='two')
```

and produces

```
random_string
<class '__main__.TestClass'>
TestClass init
in wrapped init 10
```

for some mysterious reasons code is no longer working after removing decorator param (random string in this case)

```
@Decorator
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
        self.variable = 10
        print('TestClass init')
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_examples/test_decorators.py", line 24, in <module>
    test = TestClass(first_arg='one', second_arg='two')
<class '__main__.TestClass'>
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_arg'
```

Two questions:

- is this a well-known and valid approach to decorate classes?
- why is the never used 'random_string' param crucial?

Answer (score 1):

It's because your decorator class takes `arg` as a constructor argument. So when you remove your decorator param, make sure that you have removed that parameter from the `__init__` method too. Changing this

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print(arg)
        self.arg = arg

    def __call__(self, cls):
        print(cls)

        class Wrapped(cls):
            def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
                cls.__init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs)
                print('in wrapped init', self.variable)

        return Wrapped
```

to this

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, cls):
        print(cls)

        class Wrapped(cls):
            def __init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs):
                cls.__init__(self, first_arg, second_arg, **kwargs)
                print('in wrapped init', self.variable)

        return Wrapped
```

will solve your problem.

Comment: It does not work.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_examples/test_decorators.py", line 16, in <module>
    @Decorator
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Call the decorator like this `Decorator()` and not like this `Decorator`.

Comment: What's the difference between these two approaches? I never had to instantiate the decorator while using @ annotation.

Comment: I mean, call the decorator with @ like `@Decorator()`. If it is a function then there is no need to add the parenthesis. Since it is a class we need to add the parenthesis.

Comment: By 'Since it is a class we need to add the parenthesis' do you mean the Decorator itself or the class it decorates (TestClass in this case)?

Comment: The decorator itself.

Comment: Then it is not required to 'call' the decorator - please take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-as-decorator-in-python/ for example
This is what intrigues me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is how it works:

```
# Assume you have a decorator class and a class named A which is needed to decorate.

@Decorator
class A:
    ...

# is the same as 

class A:
    ...

A = Decorator()(A)
```

That's why you need to define `__cal__`.

And here you can see that if your `Decorator` accepts some parameters to initialize, you need to use something like `A = Decorator(xxx)(A)`. And the equivalent in decorator syntax is:

```
@Decorator(xxx)
class A:
    ...
```